# Select latest date

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
    SELECT
    distinct  

        HRM_Employee.EmployeeId EmployeeXId,
      ([HRM_Employee].[FirstName] +' '+ISNULL([HRM_Employee].[MiddleName],' ')+' '+ISNULL([HRM_Employee].[LastName],' ')) AS FirstName     
     -- ,[FirstName]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[MiddleName]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[LastName]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[Code]          
          ,[HRM_Employee].[UserName]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[Password]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[DateOfBirth]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[OriginalBirthDate]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[Gender]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[BloodGroup]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[Height]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[MaritalStatus]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[DateOfMarriage]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[IdentificationMark1]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[IdentificationMark2]
          ,[HRM_Employee].[Religion]
          ,(SELECT [A].[FirstName] +' '+  [A].[MiddleName] +' '+ [A].[LastName] 
              FROM [dbo].[HRM_Employee] [A] WHERE [A].EmployeeId = [HRM_Transfer].[ReportingOfficerXId]  
           ) [PersonInCharge] 
          ,[HRM_Department].[Name] [DepartmentName]
          ,[HRM_Branch].[Name] [BranchName]
          ,[HRM_Division].[Name] [DivisionName]
          ,[HRM_Designation].[Name] [DesignationName]
          ,HRM_Transfer.TransferDate
    from HRM_Employee
    LEFT join [dbo].[HRM_Division]
            ON [HRM_Employee].DivisionXId  = [HRM_Division].DivisionId
            JOIN [dbo].[HRM_Designation] 
            ON [HRM_Employee].DesignationXId = [HRM_Designation].DesignationId
            JOIN [HRM_Department] 
            ON [HRM_Employee].[DepartmentXId] = [HRM_Department].[DepartmentId] 
            JOIN [HRM_Branch] 
            ON [HRM_Employee].[BranchXId] = [HRM_Branch].[BranchId] 
            INNER JOIN HRM_Transfer
            ON HRM_Transfer.EmployeeXId=HRM_Employee.EmployeeId
    WHERE 
        Convert(varchar(11),HRM_Transfer.TransferDate,103) <=Convert(varchar(11), getdate(),103)
END
```

When I excecute this i got the output as follows

```
EmployeeXId    FirstName               TransferDate
34             Ambarish   V               2012-08-09 00:00:00.000
54             Anil  N P                      2012-08-09 00:00:00.000
55         Ann  Rose Abraham              2012-08-08 00:00:00.000
55         Ann  Rose Abraham              2012-08-09 00:00:00.000
74             Anees  M S                     2012-08-09 00:00:00.000
```

From this I want to display data with latest Transfer date only. That is in EmployeeId 55 I need to display data with Transfer date 2012-08-09 00:00:00.000 only. What modification is I want to do in above SP to get required answer?. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Group by EmployeeXId and select MAX(TransferDate).

Comment: In above sp Where I want to add this line?

Comment: In the above Sp whre do I add the line "Group by EmployeeXId and select MAX(TransferDate)". Please help me to solve this...

Comment: If you don't know how to use GROUP BY, read up on it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx). Same goes for the MAX aggregate.
The GROUP BY will be your last line, and should repeat each column you have in your select statement, except for TransferDate column. In the SELECT statement, change the last column to "MAX(HRM_Transfer.TransferDate)".